# CakePhp 3 - save associated model failed and ended in mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i have a question about saving associated data with CakePhp 3. Unfortunately I can't figure out what's the problem is. My scenario is very easy. I want to save the following request-data:

```
$data = [
    'name' => 'article 1',
    'comments' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'description' => 'comment 1'
        ]
    ]
]
```

In this case. I want to save a new article-entity with a new comment-entity. So for both entities it's a new record in the table. So there's is the articles-table and a comments-table where each comment has a connection to the article-table.

**ArticlesTable.php**

```
    $this->hasMany('Comments', [
        'foreignKey' => 'article_id'
    ]);
```

**CommentsTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Articles', [
    'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

**Patched Article**

```
$article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $data, [
    'associated' => [
        'Comments'
    ]
]);
```

**Debug Print - Patched Article**

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Article) {

    'name' => 'article 1',
    'comments' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Comment) {

            'description' => 'comment 1',
            '[new]' => true,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                'description' => true
            ],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Comments'

        }
    ],
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'name' => true,
        'duration' => true,
        'comments' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Articles'

}
```

**SQL Error:**

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'description,
>   created, modified) VALUES (3, 'comment 1', '2017-05-22 20:36:59', '2017-05-22
>   20:3' at line 1

**SQL Query:**

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO articles (name, created, modified) 
VALUES 
  (
    'article 1', '2017-05-22 20:36:59', 
    '2017-05-22 20:36:59'
  )
INSERT INTO comments (
  article_id, description, created, modified
) 
VALUES 
  (
    3, 'comment 1', '2017-05-22 20:36:59', '2017-05-22 20:36:59'
  )
ROLLBACK
```

Here's super detailed all the stuff what I'm doing. I am just confused cause as far as I remember this is the way how I normally do it all the time in Cakephp 3. Sorry to ask such a simple question. I just can't figure it out. So do I miss something here? Can someone see my fault?

Comment: What is the type of description column?

Comment: simple VARCHAR 255 with allow NULL

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Are your field types correct?

Comment: Yes everything is correct. My code is also baked so there should be no errors in that section right?

Comment: There is no error in the code you posted. If you pass your `$article` to ArticlesTable's `save()` it should save it.

Comment: maybe try to set `quoteIdentifiers` to true in app.php

Comment: Just one other question. Cause I tried some stuff with a new installation of cake with the setup like above. If I use description everything works. Yeahh. In my personal project I used somewhere also order or sort for the column name. After taking those names it seems not working anymore. Are the reserved names in Cake? Or has this something to do with SQL Commands?

Comment: order is reserved in mysql. you can set `quoteIdentifiers` to true if you are using reserved words  in column names

Comment: `NAME` is a reserved word in `mysql`. Is the query verbatim?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to write SQL queries for simple entity insertion in cakephp3, please have a look at https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html

In your articles add action you should use $this->Articles->save();

```
if $this->request->is('post') {

    $article = $this->Articles->newEntity($this->request->data());

    $this->Articles->save($article);

}
```